# EF Core 2.1 Group By for Views

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, ef-core-2.1

I have a view in SQL lets call it `MyCustomView`.

If I was to write a simple SQL query to count and sum I could do something like: `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(ISNULL(ValueA, ValueB)) FROM MyCustomView`

Is it possible to translate that query in EF Core? 
 Diggin around I found the answers mentioning the user of GroupBy 1 (however this doesn't seem to work for views), i.e.

`context
.Query<MyCustomView>()
.GroupBy(p => 1)
.Select(grp => new { count = grp.Count(), total = Sum(p=>p.ValueA ?? p.ValueB)}`

The issue I am having is that whenever I attempt to run the query I get a complaint about having to run the group by on the client. 
However If I was to replace the `.Query<MyCustomView>()` with a DbSet property from the context then that query works fine. So I am guessing it has to do with the fact that I am trying to execute the operation on a View. 
 Is there a way to achieve this behaviour with a View or am I out of luck again with EF Core :(

Comment: int results = context.MyCustomView.Where(x => (x.ValueA == null) && (x.ValueB == Null)).Count();

Comment: @jdweng I need both Count and Sum not Count where

Comment: Are you sure?  What is the sum of NULL?

Comment: SUM(ISNULL(ValueA, ValueB)) sums the value of ValueA or ValueB. If both are NULL then they are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Querying Views are notoriously slow when they are not indexed.  Instead you can convert your View results into a list first, then query that list.  It will eliminate the querying the view on the SQL side and should speed up the overall process.

```
context
.Query<MyCustomView>()
.ToList()
.GroupBy(p => 1)
.Select(grp => new { count = grp.Count(), total = Sum(p=>p.ValueA ?? p.ValueB)}
```

I will say, the proper solution (if you can do it) is to index the view.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is curious (or until someone else manages to provide an anwser) I managed to get it work by creating a linq query like this:

```
const a = 1;        
context
.Query<MyCustomView>()
 // For some reason adding the below select lets it execute
.Select(p => new { p.ValueA, p.ValueB })
.GroupBy(p => a)
.Select(grp => new { count = grp.Count(), total = Sum(p=>p.ValueA ?? p.ValueB)})
.First();
```

Also according the EF Core team this has been sorted in EF Core 3+, unfortunately I haven't got the luxury to upgrade to 3.